# MySQL Spatial search for HSV (color) values?

Tags: mysql, spatial, spatial-query, hsv

Is it possible to use MySQL's spacial search to find points inside of a 3D polygon?

Or better still, is it possible to use MySQL to find the values on the surface of an HSV cylinder?

Comment: MySQL spatial extensions are for 2D only.

Answer (score 2):

Just so you know MySQL only uses bounding boxes for its analysis and is not very accurate. I would not reccomend using it for any spatial analysis. Look at the documentation and you will will see most features are not implemented. 
You could certain use PostGIS or SpatialLite (postgresql or sqllite respectively) to do what you require. For the projection just pick -1 which means no projection.